# Where in the javax.lang.model.* hierarchy is this type use annotation recorded?

Tags: java, javac, annotation-processing

Suppose I have:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE_USE }) // no PARAMETER, note
public @interface A {}

public final class B {
    // @A annotates the use of the type represented by "String",
    // not the parameter element "s"
    private static final void c(@A String s) {}
}
```

(I have read the raw `.class` file for `B` and can see that `A` is present in there as a runtime-visible type use annotation.)

Suppose further I do, in preparation for further assertions:

```java
javax.lang.model.element.Element e = elements.getTypeElement("B");
javax.lang.model.element.ExecutableElement c = 
    (javax.lang.model.element.ExecutableElement)e.getEnclosedElements().get(1);
// (Prove we got the right method.)
assert c.getSimpleName().contentEquals("c");
```

How do I "get" the `AnnotationMirror` representing the use of `@A` on `String` in that context?

It does not surface in:

```java
c.getParameters().get(0).getAnnotationMirrors();
```

(Not surprising; it shouldn't. `s` is a parameter element (a `VariableElement`); the annotation is type use only.)

Nor does it appear in:

```java
c.getParameters().get(0).asType().getAnnotationMirrors();
```

…which surprised me, but OK, maybe that refers to the opaque `DeclaredType` underlying the "`String`" reference, not the usage of it.

Nor does it appear in:

```java
((javax.lang.model.type.ExecutableType)c.asType()).getParameterTypes().get(0).getAnnotationMirrors();
```

…which also surprised me (if this isn't what having *both* `ExecutableType#getParameterTypes()` *and* `ExecutableElement#getParameters()` (with the ability to call `asType()` on each `VariableElement` returned) is for, what is it all for?).

Is this annotation unreadable in the `javax.lang.model.*` view of the world?

Comment: What does `c.getTypeParameters().get(0).getAnnotationMirrors()` say?

Comment: The method does not declare any type parameters, so the list is (expectedly) empty.

Comment: Interestingly, Jandex (another mechanism that can build and read models from class files) does allow this annotation to surface, and more or less where you would expect it: on the type usage "backing" the `s` parameter. I think this may actually be a bug in `javac`'s annotation processing machinery, as rare as that is. Still looking for answers.

Comment: Additionally, in my debugger I can see that the underlying `MethodSymbol` for the `c` method (which should correspond to an `ExecutableElement` in the `javax.lang.model.*` model) has a `type_attributes` field whose zeroth element has a `position` field describing where the type use annotation applies (so I guess the `ExecutableElement` analog (`MethodSymbol`) stores type usage information (?!) in javac).  That is, it appears to have been read by `javac`'s `ClassReader` just fine, but it also seems it did not "make it" into the corresponding `javax.lang.model.*` classes. I can't think why not.

Comment: Not sure it should even be allowed. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.4 --> "It is a compile-time error if an annotation of type T is syntactically a modifier for:  * a type parameter declaration of a generic class, interface, method, or constructor, but T is not applicable to type parameter declarations or type contexts."

Comment: There are no type parameters in this method so this section of the specification cannot apply.

Comment: Conversation ongoing on compiler-dev: https://mail.openjdk.org/pipermail/compiler-dev/2023-February/022165.html

Comment: Nice find, I hope they manage to fix it quickly for you. Sometimes you're "I can't really be the only one doing this" feeling is wrong and you are the only one, I had that once with LDAP and Kerberos :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed a bug from 2019: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8225377.